# Largest subset of $\{1, 2, ..., n\}$ containing no two elements whose product is a square

Tags: number-theory, pigeonhole-principle, combinatorial-number-theory

Suppose $n$ is a positive integer. Let $f(n)$ denote the largest size of a subset $T$ of $\{1, 2, ..., n\}$ such that $T$ does not contain any two elements $a, b$ whose product $ab$ is a perfect square.

**Question.** What are some nontrivial lower and upper bounds on $f(n)$?

It is clear that $f(n)\geq \pi(n)$, where $\pi(n)$ denotes the number of prime numbers up to $n$. After all, we can take $T=\{p_1, p_2, ..., p_{\pi(n)}\}$ to be the list of first primes up to $n$. Then, no two elements of $T$ has a product which is a perfect square. Is there a nice way to improve the lower bound?

What about upper bounds on $f(n)$? One idea: we can observe that by the pigeonhole principle (applied to the exponents modulo $2$), any set of $2^{m}+1$ positive integers all of whose prime factors belong to the set $\{p_1, ..., p_{m}\}$ must contain a pair $a$ and $b$ such that $a\cdot b$ is a perfect square. Maybe this can help with obtaining some kind of upper bound, but I have not been able to make it work. In any event, I would love to see other approaches for the upper bound.

Comment: Hint: show that ($a\sim b \iff ab$ is a perfect square) is an equivalence relation, and that each of the equivalence classes contains exactly one squarefree number (one that is not divisible by the square of every prime). This reduces the problem to counting squarefree numbers, for which there are known asymptotic formulas and bounds.

Comment: For a lower bound you can take $T$ to be the set of squarefree numbers $\le n$. There are significantly more of these than primes, asymptotically about $\frac{6}{\pi^2} n$.

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you! This helps a lot. Please feel free to convert your comment into an answer so I can upvote and possibly accept it (after a day or two).

Comment: This is a question about the question, not an answer :). 

Consider any set of $2^m+1$ positive integers, all of whose prime factors belong to the set $\{p_1, \ldots, p_m\}$. Is it always true that this set must contain a pair $a$ and $b$ such that $a \cdot b$ is a perfect square? 

If so, can you provide a brief explanation\hint of how this result can be derived?

Comment: @YarinMasas Yes, it is always true! Write each number as $p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_m^{e_m}$ where each $\alpha_i\geq 0$. Now, modulo 2, each $e_i$ is either $0$ or $1$. The total number of $m$-tuples $(e_1 \text{mod } 2, ..., e_{m} \text{mod } 2)$ is therefore $2^m$. Since we have $2^{m}+1$ numbers in the set, by the Pigeonhole principle, two of the numbers must share the same $m$-tuple of exponents modulo $2$. Now, argue that their product must be a perfect square.